# Getting controller name from controller itself

Tags: zend-framework

Might be a ridiculous question, but Is there a way to get the actual controller name from the controller class itself?

like

```
class SomeController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function init() {

         $controllerName = $this -> getControllerName();
         // And get "Some" as a output
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rufinus, exactly !!! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public function init() {
   echo Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
}
```

Comment: Wow, looks like a lot of request. Does it add up with the perfomance of the website.

Answer (score 6):

You can get controller name from request using `getControllerName()`. To get to the request (without singletons), you can do following:

```
public function init() {
    $controllerName = $this->_request->getControllerName();
    // or
    $controllerName = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
    // or
    $controllerName = $this->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName()
}
```

Comment: Best Answer! Worked For Me!